# install issue with python - spacy package in anaconda environment

Tags: python-3.x, installation, nlp, anaconda, spacy

I'm attempting to follow [this tutorial](http://honnibal.github.io/spaCy/quickstart.html) to install the natural language processing package spaCy into a python 3 anaconda environment, windows 8

I opened console, cd-ed to my site-packages folder, activated environment, pip-ed for install, everything seemed fine except I couldn't run the second command here

```
$ pip install spacy
$ python -m spacy.en.download
```

Now I can successfully load the package but when I run the second line below, I get the following error

```
>>> from spacy.en import English   #this works
>>> nlp = English()                #this doesn't


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\garrett\Anaconda\envs\py3k\lib\site-packages\spacy\en\__init__.py", line 64, in __init__
    get_lex_props=get_lex_props)
  File "spacy/vocab.pyx", line 42, in spacy.vocab.Vocab.__init__ (spacy/vocab.cpp:2216)
OSError: Directory C:\Users\garrett\Anaconda\envs\py3k\lib\site-packages\spacy\en\data\vocab not found -- cannot load Vocab.
```

I think that it is due to the fact that I couldn't run `python -m spacy.en.download`

**Can anyone give me an idea of what `python -m spacy.en.download` is supposed to be doing?**

**Can anyone provide a walkthrough for how to get spaCy installed in an anaconda environment?**

here's the error I get after setting the directory, activating python env, running command. The first several times I tried, my spyder editor went unresponsive and I killed the console, the most recent time I got this error

```
$ cd C:\Users\garrett\Anaconda\envs\py3k\Lib\site-packages
$ C:\Users\garrett\Anaconda\envs\py3k\Lib\site-packages>activate py3k
$ [py3k] C:\Users\garrett\Anaconda\envs\py3k\Lib\site-packages>python -m spacy.en.download

Moving existing dir C:\Users\garrett\Anaconda\envs\py3k\Lib\site-packages\spacy\en\data to /tmp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\garrett\Anaconda\envs\py3k\lib\runpy.py", line 160, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\garrett\Anaconda\envs\py3k\lib\runpy.py", line 73, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File ".\spacy\en\download.py", line 56, in <module>
    plac.call(main)
  File ".\plac_core.py", line 309, in call
    cmd, result = parser_from(obj).consume(arglist)
  File ".\plac_core.py", line 195, in consume
    return cmd, self.func(*(args + varargs + extraopts), **kwargs)
  File ".\spacy\en\download.py", line 51, in main
    shutil.move(DEST_DIR, '/tmp')
  File "C:\Users\garrett\Anaconda\envs\py3k\lib\shutil.py", line 521, in move
    raise Error("Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst)
shutil.Error: Destination path '/tmp\data' already exists
```

appreciate any help or advice you can provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hit [this bug](https://github.com/honnibal/spaCy/issues/41) which should be already fixed in the last version. Apparently spacy can't download the data because the destination already exists (may be from a previous interrupted download). A workaround would be to delete the `/temp/data` folder and retry the download.